# File extension . SVG

Tags: html, xml, svg, file-extension, image-formats

I've written a code for svg. It is working fine like a HTML file type. But it's not working when I changed the file extension from .html to .svg . What's the solution??
My code

```html
<svg>
 <circle r="50%" fill="#e60" />
 <circle r="45%" fill="#e50" />
 <circle r="40%" fill="#e40" />
 <circle r="35%" fill="#e30" />
 <circle r="30%" fill="#e20" />
 <circle r="25%" fill="#e10" />
 </svg>
```

Comment: it works well. Do you have any errors?

Comment: I know it works well. But it works well in .html file. But I want to create .SVG file. But how?

Comment: How you inserted it into html?

Comment: check Severin answer. He's right

Comment: Just copy his answer, paste it into file and name it whatever.svg

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a professional SVG, but I've had it fixed like this: https://jsbin.com/xonazavadu/edit?html,output

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<circle r="50%" fill="#e60" />
<circle r="45%" fill="#e50" />
<circle r="40%" fill="#e40" />
<circle r="35%" fill="#e30" />
<circle r="30%" fill="#e20" />
<circle r="25%" fill="#e10" />
</svg>
```